# MYSQL почему FALSE не воспринимается как NULL?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть поле в базе данных, типа string. Галочка напротив - NULL не стоит.

Перед внесением данных через скрипт PHP, непосредственно происходит их проверка. Так вот функция, которая проверяет данные, возвращает FALSE в случае их некорректности. А эти данные идут INSERT в бд, с расчетом что если они пусты, или они не соответствуют типу поля, произойдет mysql ошибка.

Знаю что правильнее вначале все проверить, а потом делать внос, но решил остановится на том что mysql сам выдаст ошибку и прервет операцию, если данные не подходят.

Так вот заметил странную вещь:

> Если попытаться внести в поле которое не может быть пустым, значение
>   NULL, произойдет ошибка. Но если же внести в это поле значение FALSE,
>   то произойдет внос пустых данных, без ошибки.

Почему собственно происходит то что во втором случае?

Comment: наверное пустая строка, или смотрите в сторону SQL strict mode. зависит какой тип у вас

Comment: Что значит "поле не может быть пустым", NOT NULL? Где описание таблицы?